# Show console.log in Xcode - Cordova App

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, debugging, console.log

My Problem is, that when I'm debugging my cordova-Android-App, I can easily do it with remote debugging in chrome and see my console.log(s) from the beginning.
But how can I see that with the IOS-cordova-Apps?

I tried to see it with safari->developer->emulator. After a while I can see the console.log(s). But I really need to see the first console.log(s) and these arent listed there.

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

It should print the log in the xcode console then

Comment: This plugin is no longer being worked on as the functionality provided by this plugin is now included in cordova-ios 4.5.0 or greater, and support is already built in to cordova-windows > 5.0.0. You should remove this plugin from your applications.

Comment: I still don't see any log though